# Is there a way to automatically generate overriding function for child classes?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I have a snippet of code in my system, put it short, there are three classes, A, B extends A, and a singleton service C. C implemented one function, and I want it's behavior customizable based on caller.

```
class A {

void abort() {
  C::doSomething();
}

}

class B : public A {}

class C {

void doSomething() {
  ... a bunch of logics here.
}

}
```

There are multiple child classes extending A, and the current implementation is they enumrate all cases in `doSomething`, but I realized the cases are actually related to the caller. So I want to make the code looks like:

```
class A {

virtual void abort() = 0;

}

class B : public A {

void abort() override {
  C::doSomething<B>();
}

}

class C {

template <class T>
void dosomething() {
  ...T specific logic.
}

}
```

And since the overrided `abort` function only do one thing that is related to the implementing class, I wonder if there is a mechanism to make this automatic that I don't need to make every child class implement it (because I need to teach other people more about how to integrate into the system, and I prefer it works with least amount of code added.)

Thanks.

Comment: How does C know what B-specific action to perform, and why can't B perform it itself?

Comment: Why do you want `C` to provide functionality that is specific to each calling class?   The caller will already know its own type, so why not provide some `virtual` function in `A` (say `abort_action()`), override it as needed in derived classes, and call it from `C::doSomething()`?    All you need to do is pass an `A *` to `C::doSomething()`.   Then `abort()` can be a non-virtual that calls `singleton->doSomething(this)`, and `C::doSomething()` can do something like `void doSomething(A *object) {object->abort_action();}`

Answer (score 1):

One way you might implement this is via the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp).... below is an example showing how two different subclasses of `A` get `C::doSomething<TheExpectedSubclass>()` called, without each subclass having to manually override the `abort()` method:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdio.h>

class C
{
public:
   template<class T> static void doSomething(T & caller)
   {
      printf("doSomething for caller %p of type %s\n", &caller, typeid(caller).name());
   }
};

template<class SubclassType> class A
{
public:
   A() {}

   void abort() {C::doSomething<SubclassType>(static_cast<SubclassType &>(*this));}
};

class B1 : public A<B1>
{
public:
   B1() {}
};

class B2 : public A<B2>
{
public:
   B2() {}
};


int main(int, char **)
{
   B1 b1;
   b1.abort();

   B2 b2;
   b2.abort();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: TIL. But will this generate multiple version of class A code, or one class A code with multiple implementation of 'doSomething'? Thanks.

Comment: @AuBee It is true, If this is a problem, you can create an intermediate class template, say `A1`, which derives from `A` and *only* implements `doSomething` (the rest of the functionality stays in `A`). Child classes inherit from `A1`, say `class B : public A1<B>`.

Comment: With templating there isn’t a singular class A to speak of, rather various classes A<X> for different values of X.  But n.m. is right, you could have A<X> inherit from another non-templated base class if you want.

Comment: Im not sure, but you could try if this can be done with C++23 deducing this.

Comment: @gerum amazing, I think [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/) is a good solution.